# Not able to load URL in featureLayer function using esri in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, map, salesforce-id

Getting error while loading layer on leaflet map using esri in LWC.

**Error:** Refused to connect to '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'    *.visualforce.com  ".

I have a requirement to draw feature layer on leaflet map in LWC. Also added domain url "https://www.portlandmaps.com" Remote Site Settings,  I am using below function.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.204754869813726, -106.83574285175166], 13);

 L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(map);

 L.esri.featureLayer({ url: 'https://www.portlandmaps.com/arcgis/rest/services/Public/Parks_Misc/MapServer/21/'}).addTo(map);
```

But it is showing error in browser console. Please see below image.

[image]

Please help how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist it's domain URL by creating **CSP Trusted Sites**.

Please follow the instruction to create CSP Trusted Sites

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Nikhil, It works for me.. Thanks!